# How to set search_path during pg_restore?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

pg_dump and pg_restore will set search_path to an empty string, which will fail if there are functions that call functions in the public schema without explicitly specifying the schema name (ie: `uuid_generate_v4()` vs `public.uuid_generate_v4()`).

How may I force `pg_restore` to use a specified search_path such as `public`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. You will have to fix your insecure function definitions.

If you cannot do that, because you only have the dump, you can convert it to an SQL script with `pg_restore -f sql_file dump_file` and edit the function definitions in that SQL script.

Comment: How may I do that if the dump is in directory format?

Comment: Just the same. Think `dump_dir` rather than `dump_file` in my answer.

Comment: Is considered insecure invoking functions without adding schema prefix? I'm thinking in small projects with small databases. When working in large environments I'm used to it but in projects with only a bunch of tables no.

Comment: @EAmez It is insecure only if untrusted users can create functions (e.g., you forgot to `REVOKE` the `CREATE` privilege on schema `public`). If that is not possible, it is not a security problem, but you still can break the application by changing `search_path`. Best practice is to either schema qualify your functions or to explicitly control the setting of `search_path` in your application.